# require('path') vs require(['path']) in requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require, amd

I am new to requireJS. Can anyone explain what are the differences between require('somePath') and require(['somePath']). When can I use which one?

Answer (score 0):

Both are same you could pass one dependency or multiple dependency as array,

for example

```
require("./inputmask.dependencyLib.jquery") or 

require(["General/UseDatatables"], function (UseDatatables) {
// you can access UseDatatables module here

});
```

Comment: In my project, load using require("fileName") fails but require(["filename"]) works. What could be the reason?